# Apache 301 Redirects where original URL contains special characters

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking for some .htaccess **Redirect** or **RewriteRule** assistance.

My client has a site that use to have poorly formatted URLs that are being reported by Google Web Tools as 404 errors, for example:

```
/calendar-of-events/wanda-hollberg’s-fused-glass-jewelry-trunk-show/
```

Notice the bad apostrophe, " ’ " character?

---

Here's another example:

```
/dining club.cfm
```

Notice the space, " "?

---

One more example:

```
/calendar-of-events/“a-viticultural-voyage”-wine-dinnerstar/
```

Notice the bad quotes, " “ " and " ” "?

---

I've tried redirect rules with no success, such as UTF-8 encoding…

```
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/wanda-hollberg%E2%80%99s-fused-glass-jewelry-trunk-show/ /calendar-of-events/
Redirect 301 /dining%20club.cfm /cuisine/
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/%E2%80%9Ca-viticultural-voyage%E2%80%9D-wine-dinnerstar/ /calendar-of-events/
```

As well as trying to use RegExp…

```
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/wanda-hollberg(.*)s-fused-glass-jewelry-trunk-show/ /calendar-of-events/
Redirect 301 /dining(.*)club.cfm /cuisine/
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/(.*)a-viticultural-voyage(.*)-wine-dinnerstar/ /calendar-of-events/
```

But I'm guessing RegExp doesn't work in **Redirects**?!

So I tried a **RewriteRule**, and still no success…

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)/calendar-of-events/wanda-hollberg(.*)s-fused-glass-jewelry-trunk-show/$ /calendar-of-events/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

Please advise, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Should I use a **Redirect** or **RewriteRule**? And how should I write out the rule?

---

I should also note that this is now on a WordPress site thus the .htaccess file also has…

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect none-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect m. to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect legacy. to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^legacy\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

---

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions and effort. Cheers.

Comment: The first thing is to put your rules **above** WP rule (otherwise, they won't never be executed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the leading slash in your rule. If you want to match a request for `/calendar` the regex needs to start with `^calendar`, without the leading slash. The slash is removed by mod_rewrite when matching against rules in an htaccess file.

And like Justin Iurman mentioned, all of your redirects **must** be before the wordpress routing rule. The order of the rules is very important and the routing rule gobbles up all requests and thus will make your redirects break.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect none-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect m. to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect legacy. to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^legacy\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^calendar-of-events/wanda-hollberg`s-fused-glass-jewelry-trunk-show/$ /calendar-of-events/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dining\ club.cfm /cuisine/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^calendar-of-events/\“a-viticultural-voyage\”-wine-dinnerstar/ /calendar-of-events/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The escape sequences are unescaped before mod_rewrite processes the URI, so you want to add the actual unescaped characters in the regex. Or you can use `\x##`, like:

```
RewriteRule ^calendar-of-events/\xE2\x80\x9Ca-viticultural-voyage\E2\x80\x9D-wine-dinnerstar/ /calendar-of-events/ [R=301,L]
```

The reason why the `(.*)` groupings didn't work in your `Redirect` is because that directive doesn't use regular expressions. You'd have to use `RedirectMatch` for that. But you want to stick with mod_rewrite anyways. Since you have wordpress rules, both mod rewrite and mod alias end up getting applied to the same requests, and that will end up breaking your redirects.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extra details…I learned a lot and this fixed my issues.